# Sencha Touch: ScriptTagProxy url for create/update functionality

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I've a ScriptTagProxy and I'm able to receive the data, but now I wanted to update a record. I've specified an url but only one url. Do I have to handle all the actions (read, update, create, delete) with this url?
If yes: how does the action is applied to the url?
If not: how I can specify more urls?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
app.stores.entries = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: "app.models.Entry",
    storeId: 'app.stores.entries',
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url: 'http://myurl.de/getEntries.php',
        extraParams: {
            username: Ext.util.JSON.decode(window.localStorage.getItem('settings')).username,
            password: Ext.util.JSON.decode(window.localStorage.getItem('settings')).password
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

I've read in the docs that you can pass an config object to the save function of a model to configurate the proxy.

So I tried following:

```
entry.save({
            url: 'http://mysite.com/updateEntry.php',
            extraParams: {
                username: Ext.util.JSON.decode(window.localStorage.getItem('settings')).username,
                password: Ext.util.JSON.decode(window.localStorage.getItem('settings')).password,
                entry: entry
            },}
```

As you see there is a url specified.
But I still get the error:
Uncaught Error: You are using a ServerProxy but have not supplied it with a url.
            );

Same behaviour when using AjaxProxy or RestProxy for example :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hering,

With your first block of code you ask:

Question 1) "Do I have to handle all the actions (read, update, create, delete) with this url?"

The answer is yes.

Question 2) "If yes: how does the action is applied to the url?"

According to the Sencha source code you need to define the actionMethods like so:

```
myApp.stores.Things = new Ext.data.Store({
model: "Things",    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    actionMethods: {
        create: 'POST',
        read: 'GET',
        update: 'PUT',
        destroy: 'DELETE'
    },
    url: 'jsontest.json',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'things'
    }
},
autoLoad: true
```

});

If you delete, create or edit a record you must call:

`store.sync();`

There is also a "autoSave" property but it only syncs on edits, not removes.

This will send over the things that have changed or been deleted as part of the request payload, it is your responsibility to parse the json and handle it.

Comment: The actionMethods you've defined are the default values, so this won't change anything. I just wanted to .save() a model "instance". This is where the error occurs. I'm able to do a sync() but this won't call any url where I can update the data at the backend.
So thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: I found that even though they seem to be the default, it wasn't actually working that way until I set them explicitly.  When I removed an item and did a sync() it was still just sending a POST.  Once I set them I started to get DEL and PUT requests.

Answer (score 0):

Hering,

I was reading the documentation [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.data.Model), I found this example in the Model class:

```
Ext.regModel('User', {
    fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url : '/users'
    }
});
```

But above you don't show your Model for app.models.Entry, have you tried that?